# Selenium IDE gotoIf javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

I want to use selenium IDE 1.10.0 **gotoIf** but I dont know how to write an if statement that compares 2 vars for equality.

**EDIT:** I am using the flow control plugin 1.0.4 that provides extra commands including gotoIf. Downloaded from IDE plugins on http://seleniumhq.org/download/

```
    <tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars.x}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars.x == storedVars.y}</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>No</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Yes</td>
</tr>
```

I have tried the following expressions:

```
javascript{storedVars.x == storedVars.y}
javascript{storedVars["x"] == storedVars["y"]}
javascript{(storedVars.x == storedVars.y);}
storedVars.x == storedVars.y
${storedVars.x == storedVars.y}
${x} == ${y}
"${x}" == "${y}"
'${x}' == '${y}'
"${x} == ${y}"

(and also)
javascript{(true == true);}
javascript{true == true}
```

All throw the same error:

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://flowcontrol/content/extensions/goto-sel-ide.js?1358766136404, lineNumber -> 120, columnNumber -> 0
```

Any ideas?
Thanks, Pete

**EDIT2:** I have been unable to get flow control IDE plugin to work. At Michael's suggestion I tried the sideflow.js user extension instead.

With sideflow.js, I have tried the following expressions:

```
'${x}'=='${y}'
${x}==${y}
'${x}'=='123'
```

All throw the same error:

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js -> file:///U:/Code/Selenium/sideflow.js?1360682689170, lineNumber -> 86, columnNumber -> 0
```

But the following expressions work fine:

```
${x}!=${y}
${x}<${y}
${x}>${y}
```

It seems there is an issue around the == operator...

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE doesn't provide a way to act on a value (if else), you will need to run WebDriver and use the programming language to provide that functionality.  However in IDE you can stop the test if the values are not equal by using any of the `assert` variations.  However, I have found that asserts don't reliably abort the test.

One way to compare two stored values:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeValue</td>
    <td>id=value1</td>
    <td>val1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeValue</td>
    <td>id=value2</td>
    <td>val2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['val1']</td>
    <td>${val2}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>Yay</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

If the values are the same, the `assertEval` will return true and the test will continue, otherwise it will return false and the test should abort.

If you just want to know if the values are the same you can use `verifyEval` and IDE will flag the evaluation depending on the result and the test will continue as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Note the single quotes around both the variable, and the text.  This took me a while also.
Not sure however if you need to use the javascript piece how it needs to be formatted.

```
<tr>
    <td>storeValue</td>
<td>id=id_one_off_byline</td>
<td>oneoff</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>'${oneoff}' == 'Jeff'</td>
    <td>Jeff</td>
</tr>
```

---

I believe runscript has to be used after each store variable request.  I may be wrong but it seems to me this is what actually triggers the call to the sideflow.js to execute its functions.  I'm inferring this from my own trial and errors attempting to solve my issues.
For integers, the following code worked for me.  with == it evaulated true, and went to the correct label.

```
   <tr>
<td>store</td>
    <td>458772</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoLabel</td>
    <td>target1</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>runScript</td>
    <td>alert(&quot;This should not appear&quot;)</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>target1</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>458772</td>
<td>y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>${y} == ${x}</td>
<td>target2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>runScript</td>
    <td>alert(&quot;This should not appear&quot;)</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>target2</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If your using selenium ide, but and excuse my ignorance, but why are you using flowcontrol.js instead of sideflow.js?  I believe flowcontrol.js is meant for Selenium RC, or Selenium Webdriver.  Mind you I'm still learning myself.

Comment: Get sideflow.js and try again, don't forget to add the runscript at the appropriate spots.   http://51elliot.blogspot.com/2011/07/selenium-ide-sideflow-update.html

Comment: "add the runscript at the appropriate spots"? what is this?

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to compare two variables then use command verifyExpression

storeValue|id=id1|var1

storeValue|id=id2|var2

verifyExpression|${var1}|${var1}

if two variables matches then no error will throw if not error will throw.

Thank you